# Dynamic Linq not appending where condition to query

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, dynamic-linq

I am using Linq.Dymanic and Linq to MySql.
I am passing my filter condition as string to a generic method.
I am applying the filter condition like below -

```
IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchFilter))
{
   query.Where("ProtectionId=1");
}
```

Please note that "ProtectionId=1" is passed to the method as "searchFilter" parameter, I am hard coding this here to simplify. This is a generic method used for many classes and I can't go for a lyamda expression (or please suggest me if I can generate dynamic lyamda expression for different classes and properties).

The where condition is not working and when I check the generated sql, it does not show any where condition applied to it.

Please suggest how to proceed here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's maybe because `searchFilter` is `null` or `Empty`

Comment: No, searchFilter has its value. And when I debug the code, it goes inside the if condition.

Comment: You need to use the result of `query.Where`, i.e. `query = query.Where(...)`

Comment: Ohh! My bad! How could I miss this! Thanks @IvanStoev